# Question on proving proposition of Lebesgue Outer measure

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove:

For an interval I, $m$*(I) = $l$(I), 
$l$ represents length, $m$ * represents lebesgue outer measure.

It is easy to show that $m$*($[a,b]$) $\le$ $b-a$ and I understood it.

What I cant understand is about $m$*($[a,b]$) $\ge$ $b-a$.

We should show $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l(I_k)$ $\ge$ $b-a$ .

and my book explains that By the Heine-Borel Thm, $[a,b]$ has a finite subcollection that covers $[a,b]$ So we choose {${I_k}$}    $_{k=1} ^n$ covers $[a,b]$.

So we should show $\sum_{k=1}^{n} l(I_k)$ $\ge$ $b-a$.

Then, Choose $I_k$ s.t $a \in I_k$, $I_k = [a_1,b_1]$ and If $b_1\ge b$ then

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} l(I_k)$ $\ge b_1 - a_1$ $\gt$ $b-a$. (Otherwise we do it for $(a_2,b_2)$ .... till $b_k \ge b$).

So What I want to ask is that : I think it was shown that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} l(I_k)$ $\gt$ $b-a$.

Not $\sum_{k=1}^{n} l(I_k)$ $\ge$ $b-a$. If it is right, then why it is enough that we show $\sum_{k=1}^{n} l(I_k)$ $\gt$ $b-a$.

Comment: Is it like a 3$\ge$2 ?

Comment: Try to prove the slightly more general result, if $U \subseteq V $, then $m^*(U) \leq m^*(V) $.

Answer (score 1):

If $x>y$, then in particular $x\geq y$, since $x\geq y$ just means "$x>y$ or $x=y$".